# Rails Ransack, initialize from front end as an array

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ransack

In the React front end, the ransack parameter is initialized like so:

```
const statusFilter = 'ransack[status_in]=incomplete';
```

In the backend, I've got

```
@params["ransack"]&.each do |filter, value|
```

so that the first line produces

```
filter =  "status_in"
value = "incomplete"
```

Everywhere else in the app after initializing, the status_in parameter is used as an array, so that multiple statuses can be selected.  So I would like to always treat this parameter as an array, not a string, if possible.

My desired output:

```
value = ["incomplete"]
```

I've tried

```
const statusFilter = "ransack[status_in]=['incomplete']";
```

But that results in

```
value = "['incomplete']"
```

I could probably just check whether the type is a string on the first usage, and then convert it to an array.  Something like:

```
value = [value] if value.class == String
```

But it seems like there should be a way to accomplish this by slightly changing the front so that I don't need to add another line in the back.

Comment: change this `ransack[status_in]=` to `ransack[status_in][]=`. That being said I have very little understanding of what you are trying to accomplish here as it seems contradictory to the way ransack is intended to work but I will leave that up to you.

Comment: Yes.  That did the trick.  Thank you.  If you want to submit that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: As for the question of why this app does it this way, it looks like the app fills the array with multiple statuses.  Then ransack checks for all of them in the query.  It seems to work well.  But I'm taking over from somebody else who wrote this app, and I just barely learned about Ransack.